# How to install dependencies which partly come from local directory and partly come from public repository?

Tags: python, pip

I am creating a setup.py for my project:

```
install_requires = [
    "rasa==1.0.1",
    "beautifulsoup4==4.7.1",
    "bs4==0.0.1",
    "pyowm==2.10.0",
    "flask-restful==0.3.7",
    "google-cloud-translate==1.6.0",
    "gensim==3.8.0",
]
```

And accordingly I have the requirements.txt:

```
../my-rasa
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bs4==0.0.1
pyowm==2.10.0
flask-restful==0.3.7
google-cloud-translate==1.6.0
gensim==3.8.0
```

Then I want to install them into my local environment:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e .
```

One question I am having is that, in the 7 dependencies, all others are from public repository, while rasa==1.0.1 is in my local directory. In such a mixture of dependencies, how can I install requirements.txt and further install them into my local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the path to the local dir in requirements.txt. Make sure the dir specified contains path to setup.py of `rasa`

```
/local/rasa    
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bs4==0.0.1
pyowm==2.10.0
flask-restful==0.3.7
google-cloud-translate==1.6.0
gensim==3.8.0
```

More details on requirements.txt can be found here

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

> Logically, a Requirements file is just a list of pip install arguments placed in a file